# Showing an asymptotic lower bound

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics

How can we show that $$1 - 3(1-2/x)^y + 2(1-3/x)^y = \Omega((y/x)^2)$$?

We probably want to use a Taylor expansion here, but we have two variables.

Comment: A version of Taylor's theorem exists for multiple variables...

Answer (score 0):

Working the general term
$$A_k=\left(1-\frac{k}{x}\right)^y\implies \log(A)=y \log\left(1-\frac{k}{x}\right)$$
$$\log(A)=y\left(-\frac{k}{x}-\frac{k^2}{2 x^2}-\frac{k^3}{3
   x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right) \right)$$
$$A_k=e^{\log(A_k)}=1-\frac{k y}{x}+\frac{k^2 (y-1) y}{2 x^2}-\frac{k^3 (y-2) (y-1) y}{6
   x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right) $$
$$1-3A_2+2A_3=\frac{3 y^2-3 y}{x^2}+\frac{-5 y^3+15 y^2-10
   y}{x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right) $$ So, if $y$ is large, pushing the expansion of $A_k$,
$$1-3A_2+2A_3\sim 3 \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2-5\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^3+\frac{19}4 \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^4+\frac{13}4 \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^5+\cdots$$